# Custom wait condition in selenium-webdriver (javascript bindings) is not working

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am having an issue with the selenium javascript bindings in defining a custom wait condition. I am writing a test case to test a button's functionality in which a button is disabled at first, but will eventually be enabled. The wait time between the states is very long (4 minutes), as there is a tutorial animation playing on page load, and the button is enabled when that is finished.

I have tried using the until.elementIsEnabled condition on the button, but that does not work. So, I have been trying to get a custom condition working.

According to the [API documentation on until conditions](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.html#elementLocated), a custom event can be coded as so:

```
driver.wait(function() {
    return driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
        return title === 'webdriver - Google Search';
    });
 }, 1000);
```

From that example, I have this code to wait on the state to flip to true:

```
const locator = { id: "Button" };
await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(locator));
const button = await driver.findElement(locator);

await driver.wait(async function () {
    const attr = await button.getAttribute("enabled");
    log.info(model.browser.type + " - " + "Polling attribute value: " + attr);
    return await attr === true;
}, 400000);
```

From the logging I have there (which is the js-logging npm package), I see that selenium-webdriver is looping that code every millisecond, and the state does flip from false to true about 4 minutes into the loop, as expected. But the loop keeps going until it hits the timeout value of 400000ms, about two minutes after the status change on the variable.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for WebDriver#wait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebDriver.html#wait) requires the WebDriver object to be passed as an argument to your function.

```
await driver.wait(function(driver) {
    return driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
        return title === 'webdriver - Google Search';
    });
}, 1000);
```

Alternatively, you can use a Promise or a [Condition](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_Condition.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you try using the `fluentWait`?

```
Wait wait = new FluentWait(driver)
    .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
    .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function() {

    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
    }

});
```

Comment: Isn't fluentWait in the Java bindings? I'm using the javascript bindings. Unless I am mistaken, I think the example in the documentation for the javascript API is supposed to be doing the fluentWait behavior.

I still do not not know why my wait code is not working.